# Laravel4: delete a comment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, nested-resources

I have a simple blog with Post resource and Comment nested resource.
Until now I can see all the comments belonging to a post and create a new comment for a post.

I want to give the possibility to delete a specific comment, but somehow I am making some mistakes.

This is the view `comments.index` with all the comments:

```
@extends('master')

@section('blog')

@foreach($comments as $comment)
  <div class="span11 well">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Body: </strong> {{ $comment->body }} </li>
        <li><strong>Author: </strong> {{ $comment->author }}</li>
    </ul>

{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('posts.comments.destroy', $post_id), $comment->id)) }}

{{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}

 </div>
@endforeach
{{ link_to_route('posts.index', 'Back to Post index') }}
```

This is the error i get running the index: Parameter "comments" for route "posts.comments.destroy" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.

This is the Index method inside CommentsController:

```
public function index($post_id)
{
    $comments = Post::find($post_id)->comments;
    return View::make('comments.index', compact('comments'))->with('post_id', $post_id);
}
```

And this is the Destroy method inside CommentsController:

```
public function destroy($post_id, $comment_id)
{
    $comment = $this->comment->find($comment_id)->delete();

    return Redirect::route('posts.comments.index', $post_id);
}
```

Someone can tell me please where I am making the mistake?

This the routes:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have put a regexp tester on your route, to check your `comments` parameter.
This error message says that parameter that you give to Laravel isn't good.

If your parameter is only a decimal id, use `\d+` regexp instead.

Comment: Sorry alex, can you write exactly what line of code i have to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Without your routes.php file - I cant be sure, but I think this might be the problem.

Change

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('post.comments.destroy', $post_id), $comment->id)) }
```

to

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('post.comments.destroy', array ($post_id, $comment->id))) }
```

If this does not work - please post your routes.php file.

**Edit:** You have defined your route as a "resource". This means your destroy route is defined with only one variable. You dont actually need the $post included, so just define this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('posts.comments.destroy', $comment->id))) }}
```

and change your destroy method to this - there is no need for the $post to delete a $comment:

```
public function destroy($comment_id)
{
    $comment = $this->comment->find($comment_id)->delete();

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Comment: I change it. Now i get this error:
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "post.comments.destroy" as such route does not exist.

I edit the question, putting there the routes

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo mistake, i modify the post into posts:
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('posts.comments.destroy', array ($post_id, $comment->id))) }

Now the error is like the one i got before:
Parameter "comments" for route "posts.comments.destroy" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.

Comment: I resolved! The form opening now is:

    {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('posts.comments.destroy', $post_id, $comment->id))) }}

Comment: The last thing to finish the Comment crud:
How can i create a link to show one single comment. 
I try with this:
        {{ link_to_route('posts.comments.show', array($post_id, $comment->id)) }}

But give this error:
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("posts", "comments") to generate a URL for route "posts.comments.show".